# Why I can use a module as a class?

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to develop some types. What I wanted to achieve was to be able to import these types using such syntax.

```
import {myModule} from "myModule";
```

I succeesed, but I don't why it works how it works. I mean is perfect that it works that way, the only problem is that I don't understand it.

Here is how my code in **index.d.ts** file:

```
namespace myModule {
    export interface myInterface {
    ....
    }

 export class myModule {
    ....
  }
}

declare module "myModule" {
  export = myModule;
}
```

The greatest thing is that I can use it like that:

```
import {myModule} from "myModule";
let myModuleInstanceVariable = new myModule();
let anotherVariable: myModule.myInterface;
```

And it works, (Intelisense and type checking is working properly) but I got a question:

How it is possible that I'm able to use myModule once as a class name and then as a namespace?

**EDIT:**

Ok It seems that I misunderstood the whole concept of declarations.

`import {myModule} from "myModule";` imports a class called myModule

I was able to access myModule namespace, because it polluted a scope (namespace on top of `.d.ts` file are accessible from another file if the `.d.ts` is in `tsconfig.ts`) before I even imported something.

Thanks @Ryan Cavanaugh for your help.

Comment: It seems like you're missing the difference between `import {myModule} from "myModule";` and `import * as myModule from "myModule";`

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Could you please enlighten me in your answer?

Comment: Have you tried using `import *` and seeing how it works?

Comment: when i use import * as ... I have to use syntax myModule.myModule().

Comment: I cannot get the difference between import * and import {} could you be so kind and tell me what the difference is rather than giiving me downvotes?

Comment: Downvotes are for questions that do not show research effort. The difference between `import *` and `import { }` is easily found: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How it is possible that I'm able to use myModule once as a class name and then as a namespace?

Namespaces, types, and values are three separate kinds of things and it's never ambiguous which you're referring to.

A namespace always appears to the left of a dot in a type position:

```
let x: SomeNamespace.SomeType;
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

A type always appears in a type position, possibly to the right of a dot in a type position:

```
let x: SomeNamespace.SomeType;
                     ^^^^^^^^
let y: SomeType;
       ^^^^^^^^
```

A value always appears in an expression:

```
let z = SomeValue;
        ^^^^^^^^^
```

So there's simply no conflict in the same identifier referring to a namespace, type, and value. Which of those you're referring to is always unambiguously determined by context.

Comment: Why I can create an instance of a class? Why the syntax is not like let myinstance = new myModule.myModule();??

Comment: The example in your question is super unclear. Where does `AirConsole` come from, for example?

Comment: Nice catch ;) yea I wanted to write `myModule`. I am trying to make a example as easy as it is possible. Of course it should by `myModule`.

Comment: The question from a first comment is still actual.

Comment: probably because `"myModule"` in quotes from the line `import {myModule} from "myModule";` refers to a namespace, and `{myModule}` in braces in that line refers to a class from that namespace.

Comment: @artem if it so, why can I get to the interfaces using `myModule.myInterface`?

Comment: Code in your example is still incomplete, so I don't know. Try removing this line`import {myModule} from "myModule";` and see if `myModule` is still in scope and can be used as a class (my guess that it probably can't) or as a namespace (I have no idea).